# PHP create DateTime object for now with custom format

Tags: php, datetime

I need to compare certain datetime with format `"Y/m/d H:i:s"` with datetime of now. I do this next way:

```
$first = new DateTime("2015/12/02 01:02:03");
$second = new DateTime("now");
$second = new DateTime($second->format("Y/m/d H:i:s"));

$diff = $first->diff($second);
```

Now I try to make this code shorter, but I have no idea how to create `DateTime` for "now" using custom format. Can you help me?

**EDITED**:

Working code:

```
$first = new DateTime("2015/12/02 07:59:15");
$second = new DateTime("now");
$second = new DateTime($second->format("Y/m/d H:i:s"));

$interval = $first->diff($second);

echo $first->format("Y/m/d H:i:s") . "\n";
echo $second->format("Y/m/d H:i:s") . "\n";

$x = $interval->format("%R%S");
echo $x . "\n";

echo (intval($x) > 0) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal is with this. DateTime doesn't compare against the format provided to it. If you've got a DateTime object, it will compare against its internal representation.

Comment: How you create it doesn't make a difference: https://3v4l.org/Mbm51

Comment: I have added working example

Comment: What are you trying to do? Compare to see if a date is the same? Check the difference between the dates?

Comment: @Chris I need to check, if first datetime is bigger than DateTime("now")

Comment: What's the issue? Simple enough https://3v4l.org/ti5h5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is check if the `$first` date is "bigger" (newer) than `now`, you can simply compare your `DateTime` objects

```
$first = new DateTime("2015/12/02 07:59:15");
$second = new DateTime("now");

if( $first > $second ) {
    //its bigger!
}
```